# Unable to get an SQL Pivot to work

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a temporary table that contains a part category and the associated part cost:

```
#part_costs
part_cat  |  part_cost
tire      |  0
fuel      |  24
wheel     |  34
```

The number of rows and the values within `#part_costs` are dynamic. I am trying to create a pivot so I will have (doesn't matter the order of the columns):

```
tire | fuel | wheel
0    | 24   | 34
```

I created a table variable that holds the part category variable `NVARCHAR(2000)` that holds the names:

```
"[fuel],[tires],[wheel]"
```

So far for my pivot I have

```
SELECT [fuel],[tires],[wheel] FROM (SELECT part_cat, part_cost FROM #part_costs ) p PIVOT ( [part_cost] FOR part_category IN ( [fuel],[tires],[wheel] )) AS pvt
```

Yet I can't get this to work. I can run my stored procedure, that this is located in, yet when I execute my stored procedure I get the following error: `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOR'.`

Previously I had `select 'part_cost' as costs, @part_names from (select part_cat, part_cost from #part_costs) as p PIVOT (part_cost for part_cat in (@part_names)) as PivotTable` though with this I wasn't even able to run my stored procedure as I got `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'for'.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use an Aggregate function (e.g. AVG, MAX) before the FOR. Also make sure to list the column value names correctly i.e. tires is not same as tire.

```
SELECT [fuel],[tire],[wheel]
FROM (
    SELECT part_cat, part_cost
    FROM #part_costs
) p
PIVOT
(
    Avg([part_cost]) FOR part_cat IN ( [fuel],[tire],[wheel] )
) AS pvt
```